# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIF' accepts this number of arguments. SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two types of dates in my report: `DateFrom, DateTo`and `EffDateFrom, EffDateTo`
Users are able to choose which dates to use.

[image]
Here is chart:

[image]

In this chart I want `Bar Line` and `Labels` only displayed within the dates chosen by user.
So if User choose to use DateFrom = '3/1/2017' and DateTo = '4/1/2017' then the line and labels  should only be displayed for one month.
But if User choose to use EffDateFrom = '3/1/2017' and EffDateTo = '4/1/2017' then the line and labels  should only be displayed for one month by Effective Dates.
So for that in a LabelDate I wrote this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!MonthNumber.Value>= MONTH(Parameters!DateFrom.Value) AND Fields!MonthNumber.Value<= MONTH(Parameters!DateTo.Value)
OR
Fields!MonthNumber.Value>= MONTH(Parameters!EffDateFrom.Value) AND Fields!MonthNumber.Value<= MONTH(Parameters!EffDateTo.Value)
,(RunningValue(Fields!Premium.Value, sum,Nothing)/RunningValue(Fields!Total_Forcast.Value, sum, Nothing))
, Nothing)
```

But it gives me this error:

[image]

So why it doesnt accept this expression?
And is any way to write more efficient expression that would check which dates to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to compile with some well placed parentheses:

```
=IIF((Fields!MonthNumber.Value>= MONTH(Parameters!DateFrom.Value) And 
     Fields!MonthNumber.Value<= MONTH(Parameters!DateTo.Value))
    Or
    (Fields!MonthNumber.Value>= MONTH(Parameters!EffDateFrom.Value) And 
    Fields!MonthNumber.Value<= MONTH(Parameters!EffDateTo.Value)),
        (RunningValue(Fields!value.Value, Sum, Nothing)/RunningValue(Fields!value.Value, Sum, Nothing))
, Nothing)
```

Give it a shot.